# How to call access method from state flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I access AddNewTicket() method in this _AddNewTicketState ? I used this AddNewTicket Class as a Navigator

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
             AddNewTicket( "CostalLineTicketDetails",CostalLine())),);

class AddNewTicket extends StatefulWidget {  

      final Widget page;
      final String collectionName;

      AddNewTicket(this.page, this.collectionName);

      @override
      _AddNewTicketState createState() => _AddNewTicketState();
    }

class _AddNewTicketState extends State<AddNewTicket> {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a property or method from and `StatefulWidget` in a state object by using `widget.page` or `widget.testMethod()`.

According to the documentation, you should not be calling a stateful widget's methods in the state object specially not a Constructor like `AddNewTicket()`. Check the [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) documentation to see the proper way of updating the state and use it's property in the state object